# Java program crashing

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.annotation.*;



public class Test6
{

    private static final   @NonNull Map<Test6,Integer> cache= new HashMap<Test6, Integer>();
    private final @NonNull String id;

    public Test6(@NonNull String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Test6 foo = new Test6("a");
        cache.put(foo,1);
        //    System.out.println("inside foo******"+cache.get(foo));
        //    System.out.println("inside******"+cache.get(new Test6("a")));
        System.out.println(cache.get((new Test6("a"))).intValue());
    }

}
```

Should i implement any methods to prevent from this program from crashing?

Comment: Could you post some additional information about the types of errors you are getting when your program crashes?

Comment: Can you be more specific? what you are trying?

Comment: what do you mean crashing? Its a program not a physical server. You probably are getting a NullPointerException at .intValue() call. We call it an exception not a crash.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a crash, you are getting `NullPointerException`

```
System.out.println(cache.get((new Try("a"))).intValue());
```

Here `cache.get((new Try("a")))=null` then `null.intValue()` cause `NPE`. `cache.get((new Try("a")))=null` since you didn't override `equals()` and `hashCode()`

Just can get out put by changing your `main()` method.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
 Try foo = new Try("a");
 cache.put(foo, 1);
 System.out.println(cache.get(foo).intValue());
}
```

**But** there is a important point. You can work your code in this way to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` since `Key` is a your custom class.

Eg:

```
class Test {
 private static final
 @NonNull
 Map<Test, Integer> cache = new HashMap<>();
 private final
 @NonNull
 String id;

 public Test(@NonNull String id) {
    this.id = id;
 }

 public static void main(String args[]) {
    Test foo = new Test("a");
    cache.put(foo, 1);
    System.out.println(cache.get(new Test("a")).intValue());
 }

 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Test)) return false;
    Test aTry = (Test) o;
    if (!id.equals(aTry.id)) return false;
    return true;
 }

 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
    return id.hashCode();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to be a key in a `HashMap` you need to override `hashCode()`, something like

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return id.hashCode();
}
```

And you should override `equals()`,

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (obj instanceof Test6) {
    Test6 that = (Test6) obj;
    return this.id.equals(that.id);
  }
  return false;
}
```

At least your code output

```
1
```

when I made the above changes.